# How do I determine if $f(x)$ has a continuous derivative on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, arc-length

When finding the length of a curve using calculus, the first step is to determine whether $f(x)$ has a continuous derivative on the curve (i.e. on $[a,b]$). But how do we determine this?

My understanding is that you need to find the second derivative, i.e. $f''(x)$. If $f''(x)$ exists, this implies that $f'(x)$ is a continuous derivative along the curve of $f(x)$. Is that accurate?

I apologize if this is an obvious question. I just feel that my textbook/online resources give much more convoluted answers than this, when the solution is pretty simple. My concern is that I may be overlooking something.

Comment: You should find first derivative and prove it is continuous. If the second derivative exists on $[a,b]$, then the first derivative is continuous, of course. The converse is not true, however.

Comment: @TimurBakiev So if the second derivative doesn't exist on [a,b], it's still possible that the first derivative is continuous?

If so, it sounds like my approach won't work after all.

Comment: Yes, in general case you can only use the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks like my idea is wrong. Consider $y = 2x + 1$ on $[1,5]$, for example. This function has a continuous first derivative ($y' =2$) but does not have a meaningful second derivative ($y'' = 0$).

Comment: The second derivative being 0 is entirely meaningful. It means the function is a straight line with no bend in it. Because bendy-ness of the graph is what the second derivative measures.